# `set -x` debugging my `.zshrc`

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zsh, debugging, set

When I use `set -x` to debug a command it output some extra lines.

```
% set -x
+precmd_update_git_vars:1> [ -n '' ']'
+precmd_update_git_vars:1> [ '!' -n '' ']'
+precmd_update_git_vars:2> update_current_git_vars
+update_current_git_vars:1> unset __CURRENT_GIT_STATUS
+update_current_git_vars:3> [[ python == python ]]
+update_current_git_vars:4> _GIT_STATUS=+update_current_git_vars:4> python /home/ismail/zshfiles/gitstatus.py
+update_current_git_vars:4> _GIT_STATUS='' 
+update_current_git_vars:6> __CURRENT_GIT_STATUS=( '' ) 
+update_current_git_vars:7> GIT_BRANCH='' 
+update_current_git_vars:8> GIT_AHEAD='' 
+update_current_git_vars:9> GIT_BEHIND='' 
+update_current_git_vars:10> GIT_STAGED='' 
+update_current_git_vars:11> GIT_CONFLICTS='' 
+update_current_git_vars:12> GIT_CHANGED='' 
+update_current_git_vars:13> GIT_UNTRACKED='' 
+precmd_update_git_vars:3> unset __EXECUTED_GIT_COMMAND
```

I can't debug my commands because of these outputs.

Why is `set -x` debugging my `.zshrc`? I want `set -x` to debug only the lines followed by `set -x`.

Comment: Do you have your prompt configured to show information about git repositories?  If so, it _is_ debugging what was executed after `set -x`; that stuff is evaluated before your prompt is printed.

Comment: Is there any condition, command or configuration which might be used so that the code in `.zshrc` do not interfere with any other commands, for example `set -x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to debug a *script*, then don't use `set -x` on the terminal (that's debugging the shell running in the terminal).  You can instead start the script with the `-x` option to the interpreter (e.g., `zsh -x <scriptname> [<args>]`).

If, for example, you have a zsh script named `ex.zsh`, then you can do:

```bsh
$ cat /tmp/ex.zsh
#!/bin/zsh

function () {
    echo "Hello, world!"
}
$ zsh -x /tmp/ex.zsh
+/tmp/ex.zsh:3> '(anon)'
+(anon):1> echo 'Hello, world!'
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Currently the solution that is working for me is `bash -xv ./ex.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Running `set -x` in your shell puts "everything" into debug mode.  But if you want to debug just a shell function, and anything it calls, you can use `typeset -ft some_func` to mark just that function for debugging. For example:

```bash
$ which some_func
some_func() {
   echo "hiii"
   ls -ls
   some_other_func 
}
$ typeset -ft some_func
$ some_func
....
<debug output here>
...
```

That'll scope the debug output to just the code you care about. Just run `typeset -f +t some_func` to turn debugging off. And if you want to debug a separate script independent of your enviorment run it with `zsh -x script.sh` like someone mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. i put the following lines on my `.zshrc`

```
alias debugOn='DEBUGCLI=YES exec zsh' 
alias debugOff='DEBUGCLI=NO exec zsh' 

if [[ $DEBUGCLI == "YES" ]]

then

export PS1="%F{013}%2~%f%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)%# %f"

else 
. ~/zshfiles/zsh-git-prompt.zsh
export PS1="%F{013}%2~%f$(git_super_status)%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)%# %f"

fi
```

Now It works like the following:

```
Documents/check:master✔% debugOn
Documents/check% set -xv              
Documents/check% echo "Debugging Line"
echo "Debugging Line"
+zsh:3> echo 'Debugging Line'
Debugging Line
Documents/check% set +xv              
set +xv
+zsh:4> set +xv
Documents/check% debugOff             
Documents/check:master✔%
```