# execute `set -xv` after invoking a new shell

Tags: command-line, zsh

The following commands work

```
% DEBUGCLI=YES exec zsh             
% set -xv 
% echo debug
echo debug
+zsh:2> echo debug
debug
```

However, when I try something like

```
% exec zsh -c 'set -xv'
```

It just close the terminal.

I do not want to use `exec zsh -xv`. The reason is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/596932/206574).

I am looking for one command instead of two so that I do not have to separately run `set -xv` after `exec zsh`.

Yes I have tried

`exec zsh ; set -xv` & `exec zsh && set -xv`. Both of these command just ignore `set -xv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh -c 'set -xv'` tells `zsh` to run an inline script that contains `set -xv`. After running `set -xv`, the script is finished and `zsh` exits (with the exit code of `set`). Just like `zsh -c uname` runs `uname` and finishes.

`exec zsh ; set -xv` tell the current shell to execute `zsh` in the current process, so whatever command that lays after  will never be executed (and in anycase, that could only be after `exec` returns), as the shell won't be around anymore to execute them.

If you wanted to run a `zsh` interactive shell with the `-v` and `-x` options on, that would be:

```
zsh -xv
```

Or

```
zsh -o verbose -o xtrace
```

If you want to run `set -xv` when `zsh` is run interactively with `DEBUGCLI=YES` in your environment like as [the answer you linked](/a/596932) suggests you want to do, then you can just add:

```
if [[ $DEBUGCLI = YES ]]; then
  set -o xtrace -o verbose
fi
```

To your `~/.zshrc`, (at the very last line there if you don't want the rest of your `~/.zshrc`  being traced and logged).

In anycase, you can run `set -xv` and `set +xv` (or `set -o xtrace -o verbose` and `set +o xtrace +o verbose`) to turn that debugging on or off without having to restart a shell each time.

And if you wanted `xtrace` to only be in effect during the execution of the code you enter (and not for the execution of commands in hooks or zle widgets), you could set it at the end of the `preexec()` hook and unset it at beginning of the `precmd()` hook (with `set +x 2> /dev/null`).

Comment: Just a minor issue, if I use ```if [[ $DEBUGCLI = YES ]]; then
  set -o xtrace -o verbose
fi``` then it prints some blank lines before the prompt. I checked, it is caused by `-o verbose`

Comment: `set -o verbose` aka `set -v` causes the shell to print the lines that the shell reads. Presumably you have a blank line at the end of your `.zshrc` after that `if` statement.

Comment: Please add this comment to your answer as well.